# field name as argument

Tags: bash, function, shell

Suppose there is a shell function called `getfield` that takes the field name as argument and writes the corresponding field (or column) number on the standard output.

```
#!/bin/bash

fieldname=$1

function getfield {

}

cut -f$(getfield $fieldname) -d\| 2album
```

Here is my file `2album`:

```
artist|title|name|year
Depeche Mode|Speak and Spell|Mute Records|1991
Depeche Mode|Speak and Spell|Mute Records|1991
Depeche Mode|Speak and Spell|Mute Records|1991
Depeche Mode|Speak and Spell|Mute Records|1991
Depeche Mode|Speak and Spell|Mute Records|1991
Depeche Mode|Speak and Spell|Mute Records|1991
```

How should my function look like. In my example is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` statement to do the equivalent of a `switch` block in other languages. The default case is written `*)` to display an error on stderr and return a non-zero error code if none of the cases matched.

```
getfield() {
    local name="$1"

    case "$name" in
        artist) echo 1;;
        title) echo 2;;
        name) echo 3;;
        year) echo 4;;

        *) echo "$0: $name: unknown field" >&2; return 1;;
    esac
}
```